# Add Horizontal ScrollView to Bottom Navigation Tab

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, scrollview

I have to create an App for the final project of my class, and I decided to use React Native for that. But i'm just starting. I got this code from a youtube video, but looking at other snippets of code I'm wondering if this one is not a bit too complicated for what it is supposed to do.

I saw other ways of implementing a bottom navigation bar that would allow the add of horizontal scrollview between all the pages of my app

So I'm wondering, should i change my code completely or is there a way that i could add horizontal scrollview to it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

FILE : MainContainer.js

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

//Screens
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/Welcome'
import InventoryScreen from './screens/Inventory'
import PatientsScreen from './screens/Patients'

// Screen names
const welcomeName = 'Bienvenue'
const inventoryName = 'Inventaire'
const patientsName = 'Patients'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function MainContainer(){
    return(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator 
        initialRouteName={welcomeName}
        screenOptions={({route}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                let iconName;
                let rn = route.name;

                if(rn === welcomeName){
                    iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'
                } else if (rn === inventoryName){
                    iconName = focused ? 'list' : 'list-outline'
                } else if (rn === patientsName){
                    iconName = focused ? 'people-circle' : 'people-circle-outline'
                }

                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>
            },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
            labelStyle: { paddingBottom : 10, fontSize : 10},
            style: {padding: 10, height: 70},
        }}
        
        >

        <Tab.Screen name={welcomeName} component={WelcomeScreen}/>
        <Tab.Screen name={patientsName} component={PatientsScreen}/>
        <Tab.Screen name={inventoryName} component={InventoryScreen}/>

        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

FILE : App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MainContainer from './navigation/MainContainer';

function App(){
  return(
    <MainContainer></MainContainer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Tried to create a HorizontalScrollView.js file but don't know if i can implement it in my MainContainer.js or App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    ScrollView,
    Text, View,
    Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default class HorizontalScrollView extends Component {
    render(){
        let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
        let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        return(
            <ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
            >
                // That's where i should add the views of each page
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate horizontal scrolling, you need to wrap your individual screens with you HorizontalScrollView Component. But if you need to swipe between different screens, you have to use a different navigator like 'Material Top Tabs Navigator' (`createMaterialTopTabNavigator`): here you can position it to the bottom. This method is more acceptable since it is in line with how navigation between screens is generally handled in React Native.

**1. Install Package**

```
npm install @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view
npm install react-native-pager-view
```

**2. Modify MainContainer.js**

You can modify your MainContainer to support navigation functionality using createMaterialTopTabNavigator.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

//Screens
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/Welcome'
import InventoryScreen from './screens/Inventory'
import PatientsScreen from './screens/Patients'

// Screen names
const welcomeName = 'Bienvenue'
const inventoryName = 'Inventaire'
const patientsName = 'Patients'

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function MainContainer(){
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator 
            initialRouteName={welcomeName}
            tabBarPosition='bottom' // Position your tab bar to the bottom
            swipeEnabled={true} // Enable swipe functionality
            screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                    let iconName;
                    let rn = route.name;

                    if(rn === welcomeName){
                        iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'
                    } else if (rn === inventoryName){
                        iconName = focused ? 'list' : 'list-outline'
                    } else if (rn === patientsName){
                        iconName = focused ? 'people-circle' : 'people-circle-outline'
                    }

                    return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>
                },
            })}
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
                labelStyle: { paddingBottom : 10, fontSize : 10},
                style: {padding: 10, height: 70},
                showIcon: true, // Show icons
                showLabel: false // If you want to hide labels and only show icons
            }}>

            <Tab.Screen name={welcomeName} component={WelcomeScreen}/>
            <Tab.Screen name={patientsName} component={PatientsScreen}/>
            <Tab.Screen name={inventoryName} component={InventoryScreen}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Here, the individual screens do not need to be wrapped with the '`HorizontalScrollView`' component since '`createMaterialTopTabNavigator`' handles swiping functionaity between screens. The '`swipeEnabled`' prop make swiping between screens possible between screens and '`tabBarPosition='bottom`' will position the tabs at bottom.

Hope this will solve your problem.